# Assigning a date value to a date field in Apex

Tags: apex, datetime

I am having a problem with Apex. I have a custom field on my Case object:

DATETIME: registerDate

I have a Visualforce page for which I use input values, and I know how to use these input values to populate fields on the object, but I am not sure how to do this in Apex.

```
private void assignFields() {

        if(submission){
            registerDate = now();
        }


}
```

The syntax for the above is obviously wrong, but I cannot find anywhere how to do it correctly.

Tia.

Comment: What is registerDate? and why are you using it like a method (i.e. "registerDate( )" )?

Comment: updated my code - this was a typo when i copied it over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Mark Pond's answer, you could also use:

1. **registerDate = System.now();**    //same as datetime.now( )
2. **registerDate = System.today()** or **Date.today()**  //if you're not interested in time part, time part will be 00:00:00

And if you want to completely remove the time, use date formatting. Below example will give you only the date part.

```
registerDate = Datetime.now().format('MM-dd-yyyy');
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided quite enough information to get this exactly right but based on the code that you provided, it'll look similar to this:

```
private void assignFields() {
    if (submission) {
        // set the value of the field on your case record
        // with the current date/time
        theVariableForYourCase.registerDate = DateTime.now();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have corrected my code, so my custom field on my object is: registerDate__c. So I am writing the following: `registerDate__c = now()` and it says that `now()` doesn't exist. Isn't there a way to get the current date in Apex?

Comment: @Lily as @Mark wrote in his answer you should use `DateTime.now()` and not just `now()`